# Посчитать кол-во групп html элементов

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте, помогите со следующей задачкой.
Имеются некие html элементы с классом group_N.
Пример:

```
<div class="testdiv group_1 someclass">1</div>
<div class="testdiv group_1 someclass">1</div>
<div class="testdiv group_2 someclass">2</div>
<div class="testdiv group_3 someclass">3</div>
<div class="testdiv group_3 someclass">3</div>
<div class="testdiv group_3 someclass">3</div>
<div class="testdiv group_4 someclass">4</div>
<div class="testdiv group_2 someclass">2</div>
```

Необходимо посчитать сколько всего групп на странице (групп, не кол-во элементов в группах). Т.е ответом для данного выше решения будет: **4**.

Comment: а можно разметку поменять ? например на такую:

     <div class="testdiv someclass" data-group="1">1</div>

всегда ли содержимое тэга совпадает с номером группы ?

Comment: Нет, содержимое разное, да, разметку можно поменять на ту что вы редложили.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/8zwgY/

html:

```
<div class="testdiv someclass" data-group="1">1</div>
<div class="testdiv someclass" data-group="1">1</div>
<div class="testdiv someclass" data-group="3">1</div>
<div class="testdiv someclass" data-group="3">1</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    var groups={};
    $('.testdiv').each(function(i,el) {  
        //тут ещё можно проверить, установлена ли data-group...
        groups[$(el).data('group')]=1;
    });
    //только для IE>=9 (cтандарт ES5)  -\/
    $('#out').html('всего груп '+Object.keys(groups).length);
    //для кроссбраузерности можно посоветовать библиотеку underscore и ее метод _.size();
});
```

Comment: Спасибо больше, но неужели нет способа попроще?

Comment: а в чем вы видите сложность ? собираю объект и считаю его ключи, что может быть проще ?

Comment: Не знаю.. я думал есть способ сделать это проще. Был бы способ получить group всех элементов в виде массива без танцев с бубном. Делал так:

    var x = $.map($('.testdiv'), function(e){return e.dataset.group;});
    console.log(Math.max.apply(null, x));

Все работает, но map не нравится (кажется я встал на путь перфекционизма, это плохо).

Comment: так вы вроде максимальный номер группы получаете.

Comment: Да по сути мне максимальный то и нужен, т.к группы должны идти строго по порядку. И да согласен, бубнов не меньше.

Comment: если max то, можно так: http://jsfiddle.net/8zwgY/3/

Answer (score 2):

С твоим исходным вариантом разметки на чистом JS (http://jsfiddle.net/mccrush/bLJE7/):

```
var vsegoEl = 0;
for(var i = 1; i <= document.getElementsByClassName("testdiv").length; i++ ) {
    if(document.getElementsByClassName("group_"+i).length != 0) {
    vsegoEl+=1;
    }
}
document.getElementById('out').innerHTML ='Всего групп '+vsegoEl;
```

Comment: а если есть group_10000 ? или того хуже 1000000000000000000 ?

Comment: да и кто сказал, что номер группы не может быть больше количества элементов testdiv ?

Comment: И в чем проблема не пойму? Ограничение лишь в выделяемой памяти для работы скрипта. Поправьте, что не так?

Comment: И я исходил из конкретно поставленной задачи.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bLJE7/1/

Comment: я почему предложил поменять разметку - в случае с такой разметкой надо морочиться с classlist (который не везде поддерживается) находить там классы вида group_nnn и их считать, так-то. а очень большое число я привел ещё и для того чтобы показать, что оно в int не вместится.